# Gateway that waits for just one token, then cancels other incoming paths

Tags: bpmn

How to model running multiple tasks/branches in parallel, and wait for just the first one to finish. Then the other (running) branches should be cancelled. To illustrate what I'm asking (what to use instead of the X gateway):

[image: concept sketch]

As far as I know, the exclusive gateway's *join* function is to immediately proceed. It neither stops/cancels the other branches, nor does it stop further executions of the output (so multiple tokens can pass through it).

Is this the answer?
[image: Using embedded sub-process]

Or perhaps this is even better?
[image: embedded sub-process w. boundary timer event]

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following:

1. Starting off from your third diagramme, wrap the tasks ‘a’ and ‘b’ inside your subprocess into another transaction subprocess (but still inside the bigger subprocess that you had already used.
2. At the boundary of this new sub process as well as the boundary of the task ‘c’, you should add interrupting boundary signal events that lead to a None end event.
3. After task ‘b’ and ‘c’, add a signal end event. Each of these two signal end events should be caught by the interrupting boundary signal events of the other subprocess or task that you want to stop. So, if task ‘c’ is completed, the signal that is thrown right after that should be caught by the boundary on the transaction subprocess of tasks ‘a’ and ‘b’. The signal end event after ‘b’ should be caught by the boundary event on task ‘c’.
4. After the bigger subprocess, which contains tasks ‘c’ as well the inner subprocess for ‘a’ and ‘b’, you continue just like in your third diagramme with a merging exclusive gateway and the “Do once” task. I would keep the timer boundary event on the bigger subprocess like you did in your third diagramme.

Here is how this would look like:
[image]

However, you could also draw a simpler diagramme with an additional exclusive gateway before the "Do only once" activity that filters out all remaining process instances if that activity has already been carried out. You diagramme would be easier to understand but the process would be slightly different from your requirements: You would allow a situation where activity b will be carried out even though activity c has already been completed. So, instead of cancelling one process instance you would ignore it. Depending on your business context, this might have certain implications.

A third option would be to use a terminate end event instead of a none end event. That way, all remaining process instances will be deleted as soon as the first one reaches the end. However, semantically, that might not be the most elegant solution because a termination is intended to signal that your process has finished abnormally.

[image]